# PLC 0 - 10 V peltier element

Tags: amplifier, analog, pwm, converter, peltier

I want to control the peltier module with an PLC analog output.
My PLC analog output gives me a voltage between 0 and 10 V. The peltier needs 12 V and 6 A
so I was thinking of using [this converter module](https://www.tomtop.com/p-e3498.html).

I'm just not sure about it. There it is saying you need an input voltage of 0 - 5 V which my PLC will provide, and it is saying I need to provide an input power voltage 5 - 24 V. It is also mentioning PWM. So does this basically means, that I will need also to provide a voltage supply that is giving 5 - 24 and then I will get the output voltage of 0 - 12 V and 6 A?

I just need a converter that will convert my 0 - 10 V or 0 - 5 V into 0 - 12 V and 6 A. Do you have any suggestions about such a converter? I really don’t want to build my own circuit.

Comment: There is almost no documentation on the page you link to. It's also unclear what the output voltage range of the step-up converter is (is it 0-10V, 0-12V or 0-24V?). The page mentions a PWM function but, as there is no documentation,it is unclear how this works. Can your PLC provide the >7A that the Peltier needs?

Comment: i think you can choose if you want to get the output voltage 0-5 or 0-12 or 0-24. my plc can only give me 0-10V and 200ma

Comment: Welcome! Please write to the best of your ability. Sentences start with capital letter in English. Run your text though a word processor or a spell checking plugin directly in your browser.

Comment: _”I really don’t want to build my own circuit.”_ If you are looking for a ready made product, this is off topic here since EE.SE is about electrical and electronic _design_.

Comment: I think you need to decide what you want to do here. Do you just want to turn the 72 Watt peltier on and off, then you could controlla reasonably sized transistor or relay with a digital IO that drives the peltier. Do you want to be able to adjust the peltier, then you could feed the analog output to a PWM circuit that drives a transistor that drives the element.

Comment: The second option. Is there such a circuit to buy? I dont have time to build it.

Comment: but i think this converter schould work, it is clearly saying, you need to provide your input signal which can be between 0..5V and an input power signal which must be between 4-24V and i will get on output maximum power of 10A and the maximum voltage 0-24V.

Comment: I just dont know why it is mentioning the PWM function.

Comment: or can i just use a DC-DC converter and supply it with a charging cable from laptop which offers the needed 6A and voltage?